# What is the best way to alias a key using PGF Keys

Tags: pgfkeys

I would like to be able to alias a PGF key to another name, is this possible and if it is, how do I do this?

For example if I have  defined a key as:

```
 \pgfkeys{path/
    color/.store in=\color@cx
  }
```

I would like have the ability to let "color" to "somecolor" would it also be possible to alias keys that have been defined using `.style`?

Comment: In this particular example, whenever you refer to it with `color=somecolor` it would be stored in `\color@cx`. Which one do you want to access later with alias? There is `/.link` key but I don't know if that's what you are after.

Comment: @percusse I would like both to point to the same macro `color->color@cx` and `somecolor->color@cx`.

Comment: They can both be appointed to execute the same `/.code`. For example, `\pgfkeys{setmycolor/.code={\color@cx=#1}}\/pgfkeys{color/.style={setmycolor=blue}}\pgfkeys{somecolor/.style={setmycolor=red}}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The approach I usually employ is to use a `.code` handler that just executes `\pgfkeysalso` on the alias target:

```
\pgfkeys{other path/somecolor/.code={\pgfkeysalso{path/color=#1}}
```

However, as I have learned from Christian Feuersänger, this is exactly how the `.style` handler is defined in `pgfkeys`. So an even cleaner solution is:

```
\pgfkeys{/other path/somecolor/.style={path/color=#1}}
```

Comment: Note that this is 100% equivalent to `other path/somecolor/.style={path/color=#1}`. This is because `/.style` is defined by means of `\pgfkeysalso` (just as you did). An "alias" in this sense is a style.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger:Thanks for the info; I have edited this into the answer.

Comment: I added a missing closing brace to Daniel's second solution.

Comment: @Daniel I would appreciate your comments on the code I posted --still finding my way around pgf:) .

Answer (score 4):

I have expanded on Daniel's idea and used handlers to define a handler called `.alias.` The code is shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
% alias key
\pgfkeys{%
   /handlers/.alias/.code=
      \pgfkeysedef\pgfkeyscurrentpath{%
                  \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{\pgfkeysdefaultpath#1={##1}}},%
      /handlers/.alias/.value required,%
      /handlers/.blank/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@blank}{#1},%
      /handlers/.blank/.default=\pgfkeysnovalue,%
}

\pgfkeys{test/.store in=\storethis,
         tes/.alias=test,}

\pgfkeys{tes=123}
\storethis 

\pgfkeys{test=this is a test}
\storethis
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know *pgfkeys* well, but what is the name/macro `\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@blank` supposed to do?

Comment: Good idea, way more PGFish :-) I probably would reverse the syntax and make `.alias` a handler that is executed on the key to link to (`test/.alias=tes`) instead of the alias, as this seems more natural to me (reflects the order of parameters to `ln -s` on UNIX)

Comment: @AhmedMusa It creates a handler to provide a value for the empty case i.e,  `test/.default=default, test/.blank=this is blank,` will print for `test default` and for `test=` will give this is blank. Not related to the question, but thought could be useful to leave  it in.

Comment: That would be a handy addition to `pgfkeys`, unless some similar already exists. You could propose it.

Answer (score 3):

Came across the `.forward to` handler in the [pgf manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) on page 891.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \pgfkeys{
        path/color/.store in=\color@cx,
        path/somecolor/.forward to=/path/color
    }
    \pgfkeys{path/somecolor=red}
    \color@cx
\end{document}
```

Which produces "red".

Comment: Thanks. There is a slight difference, with `.foward to` its own code is executed as well before forwarding. See the example on the page you provided.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides True! However, that is only if a key with that name exists. So you could use it as an alias if you have control over your keys :)

Comment: True. PGFKeys is such an amazing package.

Comment: The `/.forward to` key is on page 663 of version `2.10` of the TikZ manual, so it has been around for a long time.